# Is it better to use bytes or string to define the field when we want to transmit the file between different servers with private protocol (not http）?

Tags: byte

When we want to transmit the file between different servers with private protocol (not http）. Is it better to use bytes or string to define the field and why?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should use a byte array with a length. Some languages will regard 0x00 as the end of a string, and files may contain 0x00 in its content.